# How to get keys from pyspark SparseVector

Tags: pyspark, tf-idf

I conducted a tf-idf transform and now I want to get the keys and values from the result.

I am using the following udf code to get values:

```
def extract_values_from_vector(vector):
    return vector.values.tolist()

extract_values_from_vector_udf = udf(lambda vector:extract_values_from_vector(vector), ArrayType(DoubleType()))

extract = rescaledData.withColumn("extracted_keys", extract_keys_from_vector_udf("features"))
```

So if the sparsevector looks like:
features=SparseVector(123241, {20672: 4.4233, 37393: 0.0, 109847: 3.7096, 118474: 5.4042}))

extracted_keys in my extract will look like:
[4.4233, 0.0, 3.7096, 5.4042]

My question is, how can I get the keys in the SparseVector dictionary? Such as keys = [20672, 37393, 109847, 118474] ?

I am trying the following code but it won't work

```
def extract_keys_from_vector(vector):
    return vector.indices.tolist()
extract_keys_from_vector_udf = spf.udf(lambda vector:extract_keys_from_vector(vector), ArrayType(DoubleType()))
```

The result it gave me is: [null,null,null,null]

Can someone help?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think so, that's RDD

Comment: @Astory-teller indices are integer values but your UDF returns an array of doubles. I guess you just want it to be of `IntegerType()`

Comment: @Sergey Khudyakov I think you are right! Do you want to answer the question and I can mark accept?

Answer (score 2):

Since the answer is in the comments above, I thought that I would take this time (while waiting to write a parquet of course) to write down the answer.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def extract_keys_from_vector(vector):
    return vector.indices.tolist()

feature_extract = F.UserDefinedFunction(lambda vector: extract_keys_from_vector(vector), ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df = df.withColumn("features", feature_extract(F.col("features")))
```